How can I write the two queries in one query?
I use infinite scroll at my site and I have to return two variables.
The first one is data like 10 users.
The second one is total. Total all users from my whole table.
Now my query is this:
const total= await pg.query('SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM users;');
const users = await pg.query('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 50 OFFSET $1', [offset]);

I do not fetch all users directly I set a limit, but I have to tell my infinite scroll how many users I have in my table. So I wrote two queries. Is it possible to merge both into a single query?

You could write a subquery
const users = await pg.query('SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM users) AS Total_count FROM users LIMIT 50 OFFSET $1', [offset]);

Every row would have the total user count as further row, which you can exract.
FYI SELECT * is bad style.

If there is the possibility (even a remote one) that OFFSET might equal or exceed the total row count (or you add filters that return no row), you also get no total count from a nested, uncorrelated subquery like has been suggested.
Use an outer join instead - LEFT JOIN in the example:
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT count(*) AS total_count FROM users) c  -- always returns 1 row
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 50 OFFSET 10) u ON true

Same cost, but you always get a least one row with the total count - other columns filled with null values, if no rows from u qualify.
The best query also depends on the actual list of columns you need to return (SELECT * is typically wasteful), the undisclosed ORDER BY and WHERE clauses you typically add to the subquery u in such queries, available indexes, and (possibly) your Postgres version.
Related:

Run a query with a LIMIT/OFFSET and also get the total number of rows


Thank you! I have to add filters like sort by newest or latest. So would it be better and more performant if I write two queries ?

No, two queries mean two round trips to the server ...

ok thanks! But if I want to add another left join at LIMIT 50 query, it is ok or would it be too slow ?

@locklock123: I suggest you start another question with exact specifics.
